# How spring JdbcTemplate recognizes data types?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbctemplate

When using spring JdbcTemplate with prepared statements we can either set values of the parameters individually or just pass an array of objects.

```
jdbctemplate.update(sql, arg1, arg2);
```

or

```
jdbctemplate.update(sql, new Object[]{arg1, arg2});
```

Both of the methods are working. But I want to know how jdbctemplate knows to cast the data to  match with the type of the database column when passed as an Object array.

And is there a performance difference in two methods?

How can I log the final query executed on the database. Enabling DEBUG logs for org.springframework.jdbc package didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between the two calls to `JdbcTemplate.update`, In Fact both of your calls go to the same method. There is only one [update](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#JdbcTemplate.update%28java.lang.String%2Corg.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementSetter%29) method in `JdbcTemplate`

Which has the following signature

```
public int update(String sql, Object... args) throws DataAccessException
```

As you can see the last argument is a Java Variable Argument (...) not an Array. So you can either give individual values or an Object array to the same Variable Argument.

For your question of How `JdbcTemplate` knows to cast the data to match with the destination data type, It just creates a `PreparedStatement` and calls `PreparedStatement.set***` methods based with the Order of Submitted Variable Arguments and value and actually only checks whether the given values are of `String`, `Date` or `Calendar` and calls `PreparedStatement.setString` or `PreparedStatement.setTimestamp`. For everything else just `PreparedStatement.setObject`

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Can you give a solution to my last question regarding logging also?

Comment: To log the query and parameters, set org.springframework.jdbc.core logging level to TRACE.  If you're using spring-boot, then setting the property logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=TRACE may be sufficient.