# JdbcTemplate update, why do we need to pass in types?

Tags: spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate, autoboxing

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415295/how-spring-jdbctemplate-recognizes-data-types) helped me a bit, explaining that JdbcTemplate will figure out which column to fill on its own. However, it means that there's no need to pass in the types, so why/when should we do it?

Another related question: I accidentally passed an `Object[]` rather than `int[]` and the app gave me an exception in mysql: `Data truncation: Data too long for column 'username' at row 1`. However, the parameter was just "test" and the column was VARCHAR(60). Though I realize that `Object[]` will not be autoboxed to `int[]`, but what makes it "too long"? I think it's related to the implementation of how does `update()` use types, but I cannot figure it out...

Thank you for answering!

Comment: You need to pass them in if you use custom types or for better performance (it saves spring checking the metadata and try to figure out the column types).

Comment: So it's again a performance concern :P Thanks!